# Determine if input attachment is valid within shader

Tags: vulkan, spir-v

For fragment shaders, it's possible to set color attachment indexes to `VK_ATTACHMENT_UNUSED` (from the C/C++ API); in that case, writes to those attachments are discarded. This is nice because it allows us to write shaders that unconditionally write to output attachments, and the writes may or may not be discarded, depending on what the renderer decided.

It's also possible to set input attachment indexes to `VK_ATTACHMENT_UNUSED`, but we're not allowed to read from such attachments. That means that if an input attachment *could* be `VK_ATTACHMENT_UNUSED`, the shader must know whether it should read from it or not.

Is there a glsl/spir-v builtin way to check if an input attachment is bound to a valid image-view vs pointing to `VK_ATTACHMENT_UNUSED`? Otherwise, the app would have to pass data to the shader determining whether is can read or not. That's kind of a pain.

Something builtin like:

```
layout(input_attachment_index=0, binding=42) uniform subpassInput inputData;

vec4 color = vec4(0);
if (gl_isInputAttachmentValid(0)) {
    color = subpassLoad(inputData).rgba
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Vulkan doesn't generally have convenience features. If the user is perfectly capable of doing a thing, then if the user wants that thing done, Vulkan won't do it for them. If you can provide a value that specifies whether a resource the shader wants to use is available, Vulkan is not going to provide a query for you.

So there is no such query in Vulkan. You can build one yourself quite easily, however.

In Vulkan, pipelines are compiled against a specific subpass of a specific renderpass. And whether a subpass of a renderpass uses an input attachment or not is something that is *fixed* to the renderpass. As such, at the moment your C++ code compiles the shader module(s) into a pipeline, it *knows* if the subpass uses an input attachment or not. There's no way it *doesn't* know.

Therefore, there is no reason your pipeline compilation code cannot provide a specialization constant for your shader to test to see if it should use the input attachment or not. Simply declare a particular specialization constant, check it in the shader, and provide the specialization to the pipeline creation step via `VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo::pSpecializationInfo`.

```
//In shader
layout(constant_id = 0) const bool use_input_attachment;

...

if (use_input_attachment) {
    color = subpassLoad(inputData).rgba
} 

//In C++

const VkSpecializationMapEntry entries[] =
{
  {
    0, // constantID
    0, // offset
    sizeof(VkBool) // size
  }
};

const VkBool data[] = { /*VK_TRUE or VK_FALSE, as needed*/ };

const VkSpecializationInfo info =
{
  1, // mapEntryCount
  entries, // pMapEntries
  sizeof(VkBool), // dataSize
  data, // pData
};
```

Comment: I know I can pass this info to the shader myself. My question was if there is a builtin method to determine the validity of an input attachment, without having to pass such data to the shader.

Comment: Image a shader graph compiler that makes these determinations at runtime, based on the permutations of any given passes that are enabled, based on some reachability analysis. If any shader that takes input attachments could potentially run without those inputs being valid, then all those shaders need to be passed flag. If there were a builtin way, then the shaders can just use that builtin way, without having to be passed that data.

Comment: This just seem like something that would exist. I would imagine that implementing such a function would be easy, since the gpu knows if the `input_attachment_index` is `VK_ATTACHMENT_UNUSED` or not.

Comment: @Dess: "*This just seem like something that would exist.*" Name a feature of Vulkan GLSL/SPIR-V like this, where you can query some aspect of the way a shader is being used from *within* the shader. And no, discarded output variables is *not* the shader *querying* anything. Your shader can't query if a descriptor represents a valid buffer/texture, can it? This does not seem like a thing that would exist, as there is nothing at all remotely like it.

Comment: Dude, I'm simply asking whether this functionality exist or not. That's it. That's the extent of my question.

Comment: @Dess: My point is that you're asking a question you shouldn't have to ask, because you're using an API that *never* gives you features like that.

Comment: You're underestimating the extent of my ignorance. I'm not a graphics programming professional, let along a Vulkan/spir-v guru.